# If object is already in the array I want to remove the old object and add the new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I have array of objects and when user select an option it adds an object into the array I want to write a code to check if this object key is already in one of the objects in the array to replace the old one with the new object the user selected from the provided option [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS22j.png)

which mean this array can't have two object with the same key such as

`iMac 2021-Touch ID in keyboard`

any solutions I am stuck here

edit:

```
attribute.items.map((item, index2) => {
return (
<div key={index2}>
<input
onChange={this.handleChange}
type="radio"
name={`${this.props.currentItem.name}-${attribute.name}`}                                                                   value={item.value}
/>
</div>;
```

when user selecet option from one of these attributes it's added to an array which will be send to the cart with the item

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            selectedAttribute: [
                                ...prevState.selectedAttribute, 
                                { [name]: value }
],
            }));
    };
```

I am trying to do something like this to prevent adding two or more object for the same attribute

```
let alreadyAdded = this.state.selectedAttribute.some((element) => this.state.selectedAttribute.indexOf(element) !== -1);
```

if user select the attributes from the first time there will be no problem else if user decided to change the attribute it will be added with the new value without removing the old one, the array of attributes will have more values than it should which will cause an error

as you will see in this picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjNa6.png)

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OQPb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjNa6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `find` or `findIndex` method and object `hasOwnProperty` something like that:

```js
const items = [
  { key1: value1 },
  { key2: value2 },
];

const neededKey = 'key1';
const item = items.find((item) => item.hasOwnProperty(neededKey));
```

`find`: then, if found - update, else insert

`findIndex`: then, if found - `splice`, else insert

but if in your case only 1 key is used in every item, why not just using object like:

```js
const items = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
}
```

and update it directly?

if this is react state, you can use something like:

```
setState({
 ...oldState,
 [neededKey]: neededValue,
})
```

to update your state

Comment: can you please take a look on my post edit

Comment: @YussefMohamed to use `.map` you can still use object state and use `Object.entries(items).map` to iterate over all entries.